# XFCE running but core features not working

Tags: configuration, window-manager, xfce

Suddenly, my xfce4 desktop manager is behaving very weird: the frame around windows for moving or closing them are missing, I cannot switch between windows or bring windows in the background by clicking on a different window.

This would be the behavior with no desktop manager running, right?

But `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` says xfce and `ps ax | grep xfce` says:

```
 1755 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc  
 1794 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/startxfce4  
 1797 ?   S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/startxfce4  
 1806 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd  1814 ?        Sl     0:00 xfce4-session 
 1827 ?        Sl     0:00 xfce4-panel --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 27b5d67b9-b659-4133-8e86-12fee0e6b5a4  
 1837 ?        S      0:00 xfce4-settings-helper --display :0.0 --sm-client-id 2764eefc4-8568-487f-87e9-94ca8fc1c661  
 1903 ?        Sl     0:00 xfce4-mixer  
 1906 ?        Ssl    0:00 xfce4-volumed  2068 ?        S  0:00 /usr/lib/xfce4/panel/wrapper /usr/lib/xfce4/panel/plugins/libsystray.so 6 18874424 systray Notification Area Area where notification icons appear   
 2070 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/xfce4-mixer/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-mixer-plugin  15 18874425 xfce4-mixer-plugin Mixer Volume control for your sound card   
 2071 ?        S      0:01 /usr/lib/orage/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-orageclock-plugin  5 18874426 xfce4-orageclock-plugin Orage Panel Clock Show time and date?
```

So are all processes that xfce4 requires running? Is it just not configures correctly? In short: What might cause this behavior, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Found the answer at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1765417: xfwm4 --replace did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in `Xfce 4.10` and it happens when for some reason `xfwm4` exits and isn't being automatically restarted. When this happens, use `alt+f2` or just open a terminal window, focus it (i.e. hover the mouse on top of it) and execute `xfwm4 --replace`. This should bring back WM buttons (close, min, etc.).

See also:

- [xfce windows are missing toolbar, focus is broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257009/xfce-windows-are-missing-toolbar-focus-is-broken)