# invisible mouse shows in screenshots

Tags: 12.10, mouse, bug-reporting, xubuntu

I'm running 12.10 server with xubuntu-desktop installed and notice that my mouse pointer dissapears.  Sometimes it's just momentary, other times I can't get it back and must resort to [REISUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reisub) and shut down the computer.

I notice that from time to time I must enter `xfwm4 --replace` [to fix xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/257009/45156).  Perhaps because I'm on older (ok, old) hardware?

Are these bugs?

Interestingly, the mouse is visible below!  However, when the xubuntu delayed screen shot app took that screenshot, the mouse was invisible. (Different from pressing screenshot button on keyboard.)

[image: mouse visible for some reason]

However, here you can see the disappearing mouse:

[image: mouse still here!]

Which is *very* odd!  I double checked that the mouse was invisible.  Yet it shows in the screen shot.  Why?

Comment: related to http://askubuntu.com/q/128095/45156   ??

Answer (score 0):

If you use `xfce4-screenshot` to take the screenshot, then you have the `Capture the mouse pointer` option. Enable it and the mouse will be in the screenshot; disable and the pointer will not show in the screenshot.

(It seems to me that this is independent of  [xfce windows are missing toolbar, focus is broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257009/xfce-windows-are-missing-toolbar-focus-is-broken).)